# Handle Unsupported Content QML Webview

Tags: qt, qml

How to handle unsupported content in QML Webview Component ?

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the content? Why is it "unsupported"?

Comment: Currently there is no way to do it directly. I'm trying to implement it using QGraphicsWebView.

Comment: @ stackunderflow : I want to download file , If I use QWebpage I can use SIGNAL unsupportedContent ( QNetworkReply * reply ) to download file , but I want to download a file from QML Webview Element , could not find any thing to do the same.